# Bash: '$(( ))' means 'expr' and '[ ]' means 'test'?

Tags: linux, bash

I have been working with some bash scripting lately and been looking through the man pages. From what I have gathered, does `$(( ))` mean `expr` and `[ ]` mean `test`?

For `$(( ))`:

```
echo $(( 5 + 3 ))
```

has the same output as:

```
echo $(expr 5 + 3)
```

For `[ ]`:

```
test 'str' = 'str'
```

has the same success value as:

```
[ 'str' = 'str' ]
```

Did I get my understanding right?

Comment: You might also consider [[ ]], which allow you to do pattern matching (amoungst other things).  Single [ ] is Bourne shell syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I've got it figured out with all the kind help you all have provided! Cheers!

Comment: `$(( ))` isn't a bashism, it's POSIX-native standards-compliant syntax. `expr` is a 1970s-era antique.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the `((...))` construct is equivalent to the bash builtin `let`. `let` does mostly the same stuff which `expr` does.

the `$((...))` construct, note the `$` at the beginning, will substitute the output of the expression inside just like `$(...)` does.

the `[...]` construct is in fact just another name for `test`.

see the bash help pages for more information.

- `help "("`
- `help let`
- `help [`
- `help test`

see also:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Comment: Thanks a lot! And for the links too! They were really useful :)

Answer (score 6):

You are correct about `[  ]` and `test`

About `$(( ))`, this is a more elaborate replacement of `expr`. You can compute more complex expressions than with `expr`.